# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable?

Tags: php, ip, fopen

Here is my code

```
<?php

    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $url=file_get_contents("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ip");

    preg_match_all('/<th>(.*?)<\/th><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$url,$output,PREG_SET_ORDER);

    $isp=$output[1][2];

    $city=$output[9][2];

    $state=$output[8][2];

    $zipcode=$output[12][2];

    $country=$output[7][2];

    ?>
    <body>
    <table align="center">
    <tr><td>ISP :</td><td><?php echo $isp;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>City :</td><td><?php echo $city;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>State :</td><td><?php echo $state;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Zipcode :</td><td><?php echo $zipcode;?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Country :</td><td><?php echo $country;?></td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

How do I find out the ISP provider of a person viewing a PHP page?

Is it possible to use PHP to track or reveal it?

**Error:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fop9.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to retrieve the visitors domain name. When you explode the dots it's possible to retrieve only the isp name.

```
try{
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
} catch(Exception $e){
    $hostname = 'unknown';
}
```

Comment: What kind of answser is this?